# Parsing files with awk - extract firs tline and next only with special character

Tags: bash, awk

I have set (900) files with structure:

```
XYZ-7, ABC987654321

Some text
[...] 
Another Text

1) 8 [...] coordinates: 54°38,177’N, 13°33,573’E; 54°38,094’N, 13°33,237’E
2) 5 [...] coordinates: 54°39, 377’ N, 13°33,940’E, 54°39,242’N, 13°33,632’E
...
23) 2 [...] coordinates: 53°40,207’N, 14°32,522’E; 53°40,207’N, 14°32,557’E

[...] 
Some other text
```

I want to extract data from them with awk. Output should be look like:

```
XYZ-7, ABC987654321
1) 8 54°38,177’N, 13°33,573’E; 54°38,094’N, 13°33,237’E
2) 5 54°39, 377’ N, 13°33,940’E, 54°39,242’N, 13°33,632’E
...
23) 2 53°40,207’N, 14°32,522’E; 53°40,207’N, 14°32,557’E
```

I have found how to get separately first line `awk 'NR==1 {print $0};'` and lines with coordinates `awk '/^[0-9]{1,2}\)/ {print $1 " " $2 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8};'` but I don't know how to join them in one command.

Comment: Sorry it should not be in output.

Comment: Both answers [@sat, @RomanPerekhrest] work like a charm and fulfilled my needs. Answer submitted by @RomanPerekhrest even adds saving results to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution  with iterating through a set of files:

```
for f in *; do 
    awk -v fn="result.txt" 'NR==1{ print >> fn }/coordinates:/{ print $1,$2,$5,$6,$7,$8 >> fn }' "$f"; 
done
```

The resultant file `result.txt` contents would look like:

```
...
XYZ-7, ABC987654321
1) 8 54°38,177’N, 13°33,573’E; 54°38,094’N, 13°33,237’E
2) 5 54°39, 377’ N, 13°33,940’E,
23) 2 53°40,207’N, 14°32,522’E; 53°40,207’N, 14°32,557’E
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{print} {s=$0;n=gsub("^.*coordinates:","",s)} n{print $1,$2,s}' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print} {s=$0;n=gsub("^.*coordinates:","",s)} n{print $1,$2,s}' file
XYZ-7, ABC987654321
1) 8  54°38,177’N, 13°33,573’E; 54°38,094’N, 13°33,237’E
2) 5  54°39, 377’ N, 13°33,940’E, 54°39,242’N, 13°33,632’E
23) 2  53°40,207’N, 14°32,522’E; 53°40,207’N, 14°32,557’E
```